# Jade template engine could not add <p> tag to the inside of div

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

Could not add "p" tag to the inside of div. Here is my code:

```
!!!
html
head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/#{stylesheet}.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css')
body
    .container
        .row
            .col-md-4
            .col-md-4
                .well
                - if (error)
                    p= error
                    form(role='form',action='sessions', method='post')
                        .form-group
                            label(for='Email') Eposta Adresi
                            input#Email.form-control(type='email',name='user[email]',placeholder='E-posta adresi')
                        .form-group
                            label(for='Password') Şifre
                            input#Password.form-control(type='password',name='user[password]', placeholder='Şifre')
                        button.btn.btn-default(type='submit') Giriş

    script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js')
    script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js')
```

And it renders like that:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Giriş</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/login.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body style="" cz-shortcut-listen="true">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="well"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This happened after i add:

```
- if (error)
  p= error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so you want the `if` statement built directly into jade, not a javascript code block (no leading dash)

```
.well
  if error
    p= error
  form
    .form-group.....etc
```

You probably also want to reduce the indent on the `form` tag and everything below by 1 level I would think but that depends on what behavior you want when there is an error.

Comment: Yes. I decreased indent at form. Now form is shown. But not in well div.  I want to show my form in div which have a class named well.

Comment: See my revised answer and I think that will solve your issue.

Comment: Yesss. Thank you Peter.